# Как настроить отладчик в Lazarus?

Tags: отладка, lazarus, настройка

Здрвствуйте.
В Lazarus не ставятся точки останова. Говорит: "Не указан отладчик. Точки останова не будут иметь эффекта, пока вы не настроете отладчик в диалоге "Параметры отладчика" в меню".
Как настроить отладчик?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

В настройках *Сервис - Параметры - Отладчик - Общие* выбрать тип отладчика